# Highcharts programmatically add extra text label to y axis

Tags: highcharts

We have a chart up and running, with one or more Y axes. The Y axes are set with a min and max, and the labels are showed dynamically according to the zoom level. All this works fine.

Now we need to add some extra labels to a Y axis, with a static text. This label should Always be visible on a specific value of the y Axis. We need this so we can define a meaning to a certain number. For example, our axis should look like this:

5

4

extra label

3

2

1

Is there a way to accomplish this, and simply add some extra labels with custom text to the y Axis??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [label formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) or use chart [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) to add custom text on the chart.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use chart renderer, but the thing is when i zoom in, the axis changes, but the x,y coördinates from the rendered text do not change... For now i have a look at the label formatter.